# How should SP make a SAML 2.0 SLO request to IdP? GET or POST?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs

The [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml) I'm using doesn't document SLO or have a working example. I wish to make an open source contribution and correct this. Currently, what it does is provide my SP middleware with a URL like this:

`https://my_idp_domain/adfs/ls?SAMLRequest=nZaPawIwEMW%2FypK7%2BVfdStCVghQE20N...`

Which I then redirect to, thus it's a GET request to the IdP. I believe the IdP is seeing this as a login request.

I am able to see that the `SAMLRequest` GET payload value looks like this when decoded:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:LogoutRequest Destination="https://my_idp_host/adfs/ls" ID="_428dc0ab36ba0bbe1a6c"
    IssueInstant="2022-02-21T18:06:47.010Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">foo</saml:Issuer>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">my_user_id</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

I have come across comments that say that that this should actually be a POST request with the `<samlp:LogoutRequest>` in the body.

My question is: Should this be a GET or POST request. If GET, what am I missing? If POST, should the body be unencoded (just plain XML)? I'd love an example request.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf)., it should be "HTTP Redirect, POST, or Artifact bindings".

Also, [this](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/the-challenge-of-building-saml-single-logout).

The key [elements](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2016/01/adfs-saml-idp-initiated-slo.html?m=1):

- A NameID
- The NameID format in the Logout must match that in the Login
- The Logout must be signed

Comment: Thank you. My SingleLogin request is not signed and works, are you sure the SingleLogout request must be signed? I'm not sure I trust my middleware client's SLO implementation. What it does is add it as a query parameter to the SLO logout url like, `?SAMLRequest=encodedPayload` where `encodedPayload` is the XML that is zlib deflated then base64 encoded. It is a GET request. Is "HTTP Redirect" only for IdP-initiated SLO or also for SP-initiated SLO? If yes for the latter, what would the request look like if not a GET?

Comment: You have to cater for both signed and non-signed. The request is in the links above.

Comment: I was able to ask for the ADFS log which is complaining that the request is unsigned so I will try that, thanks. I had assumed that it was optional if configured as such by the IdP since the SSO request is unsigned and succeeds.